# What Bracha do you make on craisins?

Tags: blessing, halacha, food

What Bracha do you make on craisins (dried cranberries)? Is it a HaAdama as fresh cranberries or is it Shehakol as it is dried with a significant amount of sugar? **Sources please.**

Comment: What Bracha do you make on fresh cranberries? Seems like eating a raw lemon to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same as Cranberries. So whatever you hold for them you hold for Craisins (dried cranberries)

Source: http://www.hakhel.info/archivesCABs/HAKHELCOMMUNITYAWARENESSBULLETIN9.pdf

Comment: Cranberries themselves are debated, as they are botanically fruit (i.e. perennials), but they grow very close to the ground.  The former criterion would make them "ha'etz"; the latter is the reason many say "ha'adama" (which I believe is quoted in a popular Artscroll bracha book).

Comment: @Shalom Laws of Brochos (Artscroll published - Rabbi Forst author) says haeitz. Halachos of Brochos (Feldheim published - Rabbi Bodner author) says haadama) - IF I remember correctly.

Comment: Blueberry and cranberry both should be ha-eitz along the same debate and logic, according to my memory of what I learned from the Artscroll book.

Answer (score 2):

They are ha'eitz because they still resemble the original fruit.
http://chabad.org/1770274

Answer (score 2):

"Bushes which grow within 3 Tefachim (9 inches) of the ground have the Bracha of HaAdama. Examples of this include cranberries and wild blueberries." (From: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Fruits_and_Vegetables Source cited: Veten Bracha (Halachos of Brochos by Rabbi Bodner pg 393, chapter 22))  "...Craisins are just dried cranberries. The Laws of Brachos (Rabbi Forst, pg 359-384) and Halachos of Brachos Handbook (p. 39) write that dried fruit is the same as regular fruit for hilchot brachos. Since cranberries are Haadama (Halachos of Brochos by Rabbi Bodner pg 393, chapter 22), craisins should be Haadama." (From: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Fruits_and_Vegetables)

Please note that there do seem to be differences of opinion on the issue of whether the bracha for cranberries is Haadama or Haetz. "Halachos of Brachos (Teshuvot 203:1) quotes Rav Shlomo Zalman as saying that cranberries are haadama since the stalk is less than 3 tefachim. That is his conclusion on p. 394. Vezot Habracha p. 391 agrees. Rav Elyashiv (cited by Darshu 203:8 from Yisa Yosef 3:50) held it was haetz since they're edible." (That is directly quoted from the "Sources" section at https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Fruits_and_Vegetables in reference to the statement "Cranberries are haadama." - no further explanation is given there regarding the statement "since they're edible.")

Please also note the following, in reference to "blueberries" vs. "wild blueberries" (although this was not the question directly asked, wild blueberries were part of a quote along with cranberries as examples for the bracha of haadama above in this answer).  "Vines and bushes are considered trees and the fruit are HaEtz if the bush grows taller than 3 Tefachim (9 inches). Examples of this include blueberries, grapes, and kiwis." (From: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Fruits_and_Vegetables  Source cited: Veten Bracha (Halachos of Brochos by Rabbi Bodner pg 394, chapter 22))